# Internet Explorer CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu on a website that works perfectly on all browsers EXCEPT Internet Explorer. Is there a way to turn it off just for internet explorer? I tried using

```
-ms-display:none;
```

(I have no idea if that would ever really work) but that was the only idea I had. Any ideas?

```
<div style="float:left;">
<ul id="nav" class="dropdown dropdown-linear dropdown-columnar">
    <a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/index.php"><li>Home</li></a>
    <a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/products/index.php"><li class="dir">Toys
        <ul>
            <li class="dir"><a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/buckyballs/index.php">Buckyballs</a></li>
            <li class="dir"><a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/calicocritters/index.php">Calico Critters</a></li>
            <li class="dir"><a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/games/index.php">Games</a></li>
            <li class="dir"><a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/magnetics/index.php">Magnetics</a></li>
            <li class="dir"><a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/outdoor/index.php">Outdoor</a></li>
            <li class="dir"><a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/playmobil/index.php">Playmobil</a></li>
            <li class="dir"><a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/quercetti/index.php">Quercetti</a></li>
            <li class="dir"><a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/science/index.php">Science</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li></a>
    <a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/calendar/index.php"><li>Calendar</li></a>
    <a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/aboutus/index.php"><li>About Us</li></a>
    <a href="http://www.redballoontoystore.com/storeinfo/index.php"><li>Store Info</li></a>
    <a href="mailto:management@redballoontoystore.com"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
</ul>
```

```
ul.dropdown {
font: bold 15px/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; /*make sure to change ul.dropdown a:link, ul.dropdown a:visited, etc, when changing this line*/
 /*letter-spacing: -2px;*/
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.dropdown li {
 padding: 0 10px;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #c00;
}

ul.dropdown li.last ul li {
 float: right;
}

ul.dropdown a li.hover,
ul.dropdown a li:hover {
 background-color: #cc0000;
 color: #fff;
 border-radius: 4px;
}

ul.dropdown a:link,
ul.dropdown a:visited   { color: #c00; text-decoration: none; font: bold 15px/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
ul.dropdown a:hover     { color: #fff; font: bold 15px/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
ul.dropdown a:active    { color: #ffa500; font: bold 15px/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}


/* -- level mark -- */

ul.dropdown ul {
 background-color: #cc0000;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
 font-size: 12px;
 letter-spacing: normal;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 2px black;
 -ms-display:none;
}

* html ul.dropdown ul {
 width: 960px;
}

    ul.dropdown ul li {
     font-weight: bold;
     box-shadow: none;
     color: #fff;
    }

    /* -- level mark -- */

    ul.dropdown ul ul {
     margin-top: 5px;
     text-transform: none;
     box-shadow: none;
    }

        ul.dropdown ul ul li {
         font-weight: normal;
        }





ul.dropdown *.dir {
 padding-right: 30px;
     /*background-image: url(../../../../images/lwis.celebrity/nav-arrow-down.png);*/
 background-position: 100% 50%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul.dropdown li.hover,
    ul.dropdown li:hover.dir {
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul.dropdown ul *.dir {
 background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: You might want to include the CSS for your menu. People might even be able to tell you how to make it work if they can see what you've tried.

Comment: Are you viewing this locally?  I had run into a problem with an intranet site where the menu was breaking only in IE.  Turns out that IE 9 automatically assumed that all intranet sites should be viewed in compatibility mode which broke my menu.  Turning it off, solved the issue for me.

Comment: It's not local and compatibility mode is off

Comment: I have a few more stylesheets just for the dropdown menu but I don't want to paste it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using conditional comments to avoid IE executing the code:

```
<![if !IE]>

Your code

<![endif]>
```

Comment: If this didn't alter the code for Firefox then that would have been awesome. It did it for explorer when I tried it but then my firefox version was also messed up

Comment: What's the same code you just gave me for firefox, chrome, and safari?

Comment: To my knowledge, conditional comments are only supported by IE

You can try using:

<![if !lte IE 9]>

Your code

<![endif]>

Answer (score 0):

There's always the IE css hacks, too.  Although they're not preferable, if it's just a real quick and dirty thing, and you need to target IE7 and below, you can just place a * in front of the property.

Example:

```
div.box {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
}
```

That will only show inline in IE7 and below.

Comment: Yeah... IE9 is messing it up as well though